# node error ECONNREFUSED 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, csv, backend

Apologies for vagueness of this post. I will give as much info as I cant hand over code for privacy reasons. But just wondering, I tried too search for this error but no dice.

Essentially I am firing a URL to a site. It uses a script. It worked before. It seems to fire the data I want, followed by an error....on the client side it does not seem to receive.

its is running running node and the files contain node_modules.
I am mostly front end and never deal with this sort of work

With the data I can give you with the error message can anyone help.

Once again sincere apologies of vagueness

```
PS C:\gobbler-URL> npm install

added 27 packages, and audited 28 packages in 1s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\gobbler-URL>
PS C:\gobbler-URL> node gobbler.js
firing postbacks for./tester-url
processingBook1tester.csv
postback firing to http://THIS-IS-THE-URL-I-AM-FIRING
CSV file successfully processed
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1246:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 80
}
```

Comment: `http://THIS-IS-THE-URL-I-AM-FIRING`  From the same machine your trying this URL,  do you get anything if you put it into a browser?.

Comment: `http://THIS-IS-THE-URL-I-AM-FIRING` resolves to `localhost`. Is there any process listening on port 80 on your machine?

Comment: Hey Keith, I am testing with a dummy url that doesnt go anywhere. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Hey Derpirscher, I basically install a node package and then run the with node gobbler.js and this usually fires the url. It is laid out the same way on other files on the same computer I am on

Comment: `url that doesnt go anywhere`  Yeah, that's not going to help.

Comment: I got a correct postback and still doesnt work

Comment: @keith Could I perhaps maybe privately send you the code?